# How to fill an ellipse with different colors in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

am developing a WP8.1 app using xaml and C#.
i want to have a button or ellipse filled with multi colors like the below picture. How can i achieve this except using pie chart control?
I just need it in max height of 80 and width of 80
Can someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1):

You use Arc shaped control to create this shape.

> ```
> xmlns:es="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Shapes;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Drawing"
> ```

```
           <Grid>
                 <es:Arc ArcThickness="1" ArcThicknessUnit="Percent" EndAngle="360" Fill="#FF82ECDD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="293" Margin="0,0,0,-100" Stretch="None" StartAngle="61" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294"/>
                 <es:Arc ArcThickness="1" ArcThicknessUnit="Percent" EndAngle="360" Fill="#FF38B5E4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="293" Margin="0,0,0,-100" Stretch="None" StartAngle="298" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <es:Arc.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="61.609"/>
                 </es:Arc.RenderTransform>
                 </es:Arc>
                 <es:Arc ArcThickness="1" ArcThicknessUnit="Percent" EndAngle="360" Fill="#FF349AD4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="293" Margin="0,0,0,-100" Stretch="None" StartAngle="179" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                 <es:Arc.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="-119.36"/>
                 </es:Arc.RenderTransform>
                 </es:Arc>
             </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for the help.. Thank you

Comment: Don't forgot to mark it as answered if it solved your problem, :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a single ellipse into path and then remove one point in the path to make it a semicircle. 
Have three semicircle rotated at proper angle to achieve something similar to the image above.

Comment: Hey Chirag.. I tried various ways but it did not work out. Can you please share a sample code?

Comment: you have to use blend, right click on the ellipse convert to path and click on one of the four points and press delete. Youll get the semicircle.